# How do you say "runder Geburtstag" in English?

Tags: phrase-request, german-to-english

When someone turns 10, 20, 30, 40, 50... it is common in Germany to say that they are celebrating their "runder Geburtstag" which is usually celebrated in a larger way, inviting a larger circle of people, etc.

When I translate this into English, I usually say, "she is celebrating her rounded birthday" but I don't think people really understand that out of a German context.

Is there a common expression for this in English?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but IMHO it's more about **[English](http://english.stackexchange.com/)** than **German Language and Usage**. Maybe we get some more esp. colloquial variants from there, in addition to Takkat's nice answer?

Comment: Fully agree with @tohuwawohu here. As people at ELU may not be able/willing to translate from German there still may be some additional or better ideas there.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: An English equivalent for the German phrase is being asked here, How they could translate German to English on EL&U? I guess it's an on-topic question as Takkat has answered completely right.

Comment: No - it is not problem of the german term or language, but of the english term. Shall we translate German->French as well? German -> Latin, German -> Suaheli? It's off topic. -1

Comment: @userunknown: When one side is *German* it's reasonably O.K. Read [faq](http://german.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) before downvoting the question you don't like. Translation questions are completely on-topic.

Comment: I would consider "rounded" birthday strange. Is it not *really* his 30th birthay, but maybe the 32th, and you rounded it to 30?

Comment: @userunknown: If we get a reasonable amount of users speaking Suaheli, I'm perfectly fine with questions in this direction (provided that this are not simple words normally found in a dictionary, I am on your side in this case: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/343/when-is-a-translation-request-to-german-off-topic). When it's time that we get the "german-to-suaheli" tag this will go on my ignore list, as I can't contribute there.

Comment: @user508: The FAQ says: "Translations requests **from** German to English should be restricted to cases where a profound knowledge of German is needed for understanding a phrase or an idiom." As the brief summarization in the beginning of the question aptly demonstrates, the concept can be explained in a single English sentence, so no profound knowledge of German is required.

Comment: For some special birthdays, there is some slang: the big four-oh, the big five-oh.  Example: https://www.zazzle.com/balloon_40th_fouroh_photo_birthday_invite-161571012599394710. // You can indeed ask this sort of question at English Language & Usage SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best English match to *"Runder Geburtstag"* may be

> Milestone birthday

Colloquial (where *"runder Geburtstag"* may also be used) we may say

> The big four-O *(or any other number)*

Comment: I've only ever heard someone say "big <Number>-oh". I can't say I've ever heard someone say "milestone birthday", but I think it would be understood just as well.

Answer (score 1):

One (slang) of describing such a birthday is a birthday with a new "handle" (3-, 4,-, etc.)

This expression (and others connected with this question) is not all that common, probably because the basic idea is not as prevalent in America as in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just saying she is celebrating her 30th birthday, 40th birthday, etc. and likewise Happy 40th Birthday, Happy 30th Birthday, etc.   I believe we (Americans at least) tend to more use the number, then have a special term for every birthday in that category.  People understand from the number that it is rounded, and, therefore, a more "special" birthday.